# Can't find what's throwing a null point exception error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
try {
    float newRep = Float.parseFloat(split[1]);
    String target = split[0];
    for (File file : getDataFolder().listFiles()) {
        if (file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(target + ".yml")) {
            File targetFile = file;
            try {
                FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(targetFile);
                config.set("data.rep", newRep);
                config.save(targetFile);
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target + ChatColor.RED
                        + "'s rep is now set to " + ChatColor.GREEN + newRep);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Must be a number!");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player not found!");
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    sender.sendMessage("Unknown pointer error!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Basically something there is throwing a null point error. Really bamboozled. All the code is doing is trying to open a yaml file based on `split[0]` array. Then change one of the values to in the yaml to the string `split[1]` (which is passed to a float).

Here is the stack trace:

```
23:25:18 [SEVERE] java.lang.NullPointerException
23:25:18 [SEVERE]   at com.github.scullyking.reputation.Command_Set.onCommand(Command_Set.java:33)
23:25:18 [SEVERE]   at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44)
23:25:18 [SEVERE]   at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:191)
23:25:18 [SEVERE]   at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:523)
23:25:18 [SEVERE]   at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:512)
23:25:18 [SEVERE]   at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.DedicatedServer.ar(DedicatedServer.java:262)
23:25:18 [SEVERE]   at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.DedicatedServer.t(DedicatedServer.java:227)
23:25:18 [SEVERE]   at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:486)
23:25:18 [SEVERE]   at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:419)
23:25:18 [SEVERE]   at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:582)'
```

Ok, so line 33 is the for loop.

Comment: What line does the stacktrace point to? Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: You should stop catching the `NullPointerException`. The resulting output gives much more information than "Unknown pointer error!", and if you posted that output, we could actually answer your question.

Comment: BTW, is this the [se] api?

Comment: Ok added, I really need to learn to read stack traces.

Comment: Which line is line 33?, you haven't posted the whole file so we can't count the line number ourselves.

Comment: Line 33 is the for loop

Comment: In which case `getDataFolder()` does not return a folder. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()): _Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory_.

Comment: That would be, because some one swallowed the exception and replaced it with a totally useless string...

Comment: OP, I would strongly recommend that you learn to use a debugger.

Comment: This is very strange as I use this identical for loop elsewhere in the program and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getDataFolder()` is returning `null`.

You then call `.listFiles()` on what's returned, and boom.

Comment: Maybe the environment is different this time.

Comment: @Scully, step into `getDataFolder()` using debugger to find the issue.

Comment: @Bohemian It could be that `getDataFolder()` doesn't return `null` but `listFiles()` does when it's called on something that isn't a folder.

Comment: Here's my theory, if I've got two classes extending JavaPlugin. And I call getDataFolder() in both classes. Are they looking for different instances of the data folder. Hence why this for loop works in my primary class but not in this class. Correct me if I'm wrong (I still haven't fully grasped OOP).